# Cannot recognize the DataFrame for Java on spark in the Intellij platform

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am quite new to Spark and I tried to manipulate some data using DataFrame library included in the spark library.

While doing the task, I have been facing the error indicating that my IDE cannot resolve the symbol `DataFrame`. I searched the related issues on the Internet and followed the solution they recommended, but the result didn't resolve my case.

Below is my code and the error throw `Cannot resolve symbol DataFrame`.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputFile = args[1];
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Data Transformation")
                .set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                .setMaster("local[*]");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

        //below statement throw error in the DataFrame declaration.
        DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json");

        sc.stop();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

and my pom.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bistel</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I don't know why I got this error although I specified the all the relevant libraries such as spark-core and spark-sql. I resolved the same issues on the Scala language but I couldn't for the Java.

Comment: Unrelated to the specific question, Is there a reason you are using spark 2.0.1 with older sematics? You seem to be using spark context and sql context instead of spark session and you are using artifacts with scala 2.10 instead of 2.11

Comment: Since I am quite new to spark, I am very confused to the numerous versions included in the spark platform. Especially, I didn't know what versions of different platform (spark, scala..) are compatible with to use them well. I would appreciate it if you could give me a guidance for the usage of spark and scala versions or let me know any websites about the spark versions.

Comment: The version in the pom (2.0.1 in your case) is the spark version. In general spark version 2.X.X has had many changes (and actually can break some code written for 1.6.X). If at all possible, you should be working with spark 2 versions as all new features are aimed there. Specifically spark 2.X.X does not guarantee compatibility with spark 1.X.X. The scala version is defined in the artifact id (_2.10 or _2.11). Since these two scala versions are not compatible, you have to make sure everything you use would be with a compatible version. I would suggest using 2.11 for spark 2.X.X (the default).

Comment: @AssafMendelson Greats. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was version issue. The problem is the version of spark library I used. The version of 2.0.1 does not provide the DataFrame. I downgraded my version to 1.6.0 and I am able to include import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.

Below is my new pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bistel</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: 2.1.0 provides dataframe. It is just defined differently than in 1.6. In 1.6 DataFrame is a full class. In 2.1 (or 2.0.1) it is an alias for Dataset[Row]

Comment: How is it, that this comment isn't the first result that comes up, when I google Spark 2.1 DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the import for Dataframe:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Comment: The problem was version issue. The problem is the version of spark library I used. The version of 2.0.1 does not provide the DataFrame. I downgraded my version to 1.6.0 and I am able to include `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`. Thanks.